# PySpark Python worker crashes at `.collect()` when using tensorflow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to optimize a neural network coded with Tensorflow by setting different seeds and parallelize each training stage with PySpark. This was inspired by mixing RL and Genetic Algorithms. My problem is that when I run the code, when doing `.collect()` it crashes and I can't figure it out why. I also ran the code without using the `mainSpark` function in order to check if the error was in other place and it worked fine. What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I'm using tensorflow 2.6 and pyspark 3.0.1

The code is as follows:

```
def mainSpark(data,seed,main_folder,train=True):
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        environment = Enviroment(data = data)
        agent = Agent(seed,environment.state_dim,environment.action_space,main_folder)
        reward,_ = playSpark(environment,agent,train)
        g.finalize()
    return reward,environment

def playSpark(env,agent,train=True):
    state = env.reset(train)
    done = False
    episode_reward = 0
    reward = 0
    while not done:
        action = agent.act(state)
        state,reward,done,info = env.step(action)
        episode_reward+=reward
    return episode_reward,env


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MAIN_FOLDER = 'rl_train_results/rl_normal_environment_v1'
    spark = ps.sql.SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('sparkRunGeneticOpt').getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    for generation in range(N_GENS):
        individuals = [np.random.randint(2,size=10) for _ in range(10)]
        generation_scores = sc.parallelize(individuals).map(
            lambda s: (s,mainSpark(_price,s,MAIN_FOLDER))
        )
        generation_scores = generation_scores.collect()
        print(generation_scores)
```

The model that is inside the agent is like this:

```
class Agent():
    def __init__(self,seed,space_dim):
        self.space_dim = space_dim
        self.seed = seed
        int_seed = int(seed,2)
        self.set_seed(int_seed)
            
    def create_model(self):
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(self.space_dim,),name='inputs'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation='relu',name='d1'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,activation='relu',name='d2'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax',name='output')
        ])
        return model

    def set_seed(self,seed=None):
        if seed is None:
            tf.random.set_seed(int(self.seed,2))
        else:
            if isinstance(seed,str):
                seed = int(seed,2)
            tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

And the error log is this:

```
21/11/05 01:08:47 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:536)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:643)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1004)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:628)
        ... 29 more
21/11/05 01:08:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, Asus, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exite
d unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:536)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:643)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1004)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:628)
        ... 29 more

21/11/05 01:08:48 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
21/11/05 01:08:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, Asus, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
  File ".\mainSpark.py", line 125, in <module>
    generation_scores = generation_scores.collect()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 889, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0
.0 (TID 0, Asus, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:536)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:643)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1004)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:628)
        ... 29 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2120)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2139)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2164)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:536)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:643)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:621)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1004)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:628)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: Why are you running it over a local[*]? , 
is your code working without spark ? 
are you trying to run them in parallel using spark , is the only requirement from spark is to parallelize them ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @AdityaVikramSingh. I'm running over local[*] because I'm running this in my local machine (windows), as it is still in development. I'm trying to run them in parallel with spark because I think its more resource efficient, but maybe I'm wrong or I'm using spark for something that is not intended for. I do not discard using other ways. I also aim to run this in the cloud.